# Exchange Powershell : Is it possible to differentiate on prem and cloud based distribution group?

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I'm trying to create a script that must count the number of cloud and on prem based distribution group in a hybrid Exchange setup (on-prem + office 365).

I already did that with the users mailbox, it's possible to differentiate them by using the RecipientTypeDetails attribute. A "UserMailBox" represents an on prem user and a "MailUser" represents a cloud user.

Is there something similar for distribution group ? I didn't find the answer.

Thank your for your help, regards

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer. Here are the cmdlets used by type of mailboxes :

```
"USER_ONPREM" = (Get-Mailbox -Resultsize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails "UserMailbox").Count
"USER_CLOUD" = (Get-Recipient -Resultsize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails "RemoteUserMailbox").Count
"SHARED_ONPREM" = (Get-Mailbox -Resultsize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails "SharedMailbox").Count
"SHARED_CLOUD" = (Get-Recipient -Resultsize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails "RemoteSharedMailbox").Count
"EQUIPMENT_ONPREM" = (Get-Mailbox -Resultsize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails "EquipmentMailbox").Count
"EQUIPMENT_CLOUD" = (Get-Recipient -Resultsize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails "RemoteEquipmentMailbox").Count
"ROOM_ONPREM" = (Get-Mailbox -Resultsize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails "RoomMailbox").Count
"ROOM_CLOUD" = (Get-Recipient -Resultsize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails "RemoteRoomMailbox").Count
"DL_ONPREM" = (Get-DistributionGroup -Resultsize Unlimited | where {$_.IsDirSynced -eq $False}).Count
"DL_CLOUD" = (Get-DistributionGroup -Resultsize Unlimited | where {$_.IsDirSynced -eq $True}).Count
```

To get on-prem mailboxes, it's just needed to use Get-Mailbox and filter by type.

To get remote mailboxes (i.e. mailboxes that are synced/migrated from onprem environment) it's possible to use Get-RemoteMailbox or Get-Recipient and filter by type with the suffix "Remote" added.

Finally to get "cloud only" mailboxes, it's only possible to retrieve them using an Exchange Online connection and from there we can verify which mailboxes are not synced with the attribute $_.IsDirSynced.

More infos : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/594318/exchange-powershell-is-it-possible-to-differentiat.html

When onPrem IsDirSynced indicates if the mailbox is synced to the cloud and when in the cloud IsDirSynced indicates if the mailbox is synced to on prem. Not very intuitive, but hey, it's Microsoft I guess.

I compared the result with what the ECP returns (The ECP classifies account as OnPrem or Office 365) and the numbers are correct.